# how to return std file streams

Tags: c++, g++, std

I am working on a "filesystem" for my application to handle file operations like listing, creating, removing files and directories, and get file data. I want to use std::fstream for that because its safer and easier to format than the C FILE Handler. But i cannot return a stream object from the function (it doesn't have a copy c'tor) and when I am trying to return the reference I am getting a warning (i not warning doesn't mean that much but I am trying to fix every possible warning in my app and I did all of it until now): "warning: returning a reference to temporary". What can I do? If someone encountered this situation and found a better way to handle it, please tell.

EDIT:

```
std::ofstream &Filesystem::createFile(const String &str) {
   std::ofstream file(str);
   return file;
}
```

this is what I am trying to achieve. But due to the warning i am looking for another way.

Thanks in advance,
Gasim Gasimzada

Comment: Post your code, including the exact compiler messages and the lines which are causing them.

Comment: @Gasim: Please post the code, that would help more than describing the changes.

Comment: `warning: returning a reference to temporary` means exactly that: you made a temporary object, then tried to return a reference to it. That doesn't work since the temporary is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

Use a smart pointer, something like may work (or one of the newer `std::unique_ptr`, etc.)

```
std::auto_ptr<std::iostream> foo()
{
  return std::auto_ptr<std::iostream>(new fstream(...));
}
```

Comment: +1. I'd personally find a pointer to `std::iostream` cleaner in many situations, since its more general.

Comment: @larsmans, true, however how would you convey the ownership? Who's responsible for cleaning up etc.

Comment: By pointer, I don't necessarily mean "bare pointer". `unique_ptr` would be the best option for this one.

Comment: @larsmans, oh crap - sorry, I just got your comment now... oops, I'll fix the answer

Comment: using pointers was one of the ideas i had but i am having troubles doing something like: `foo() << "Hello World " << 10*10 << ClsThatSupportsStreams;`i have to dereference it to get it to work.

Comment: i have gotten an idea but there is a memory leak happening here: `ofstream& createfile(string name) { ofstream * file = new ofstream(name.c_str()); return *file; }` the file is not getting deleted. boost::shared_ptr, std::auto_ptr doesn't work in that case too: it removes the pointer out of scope which leads to segmentation fault when i try to do `createfile("test.txt") << "hello world"`

Comment: Death to `auto_ptr`. Long live `auto_ptr`!!

Answer (score 4):

In C++0x stream objects are movable so you can in fact return a stream object by value:

```
// Perfectly valid C++0x
std::ofstream f()
{
    return std::ofstream("pwnies.txt");
}
```

The Visual C++ 2010 Standard Library implementation includes movable streams, as does libc++.  If you need to target older compiler/library implementations that don't support rvalue references and movable streams, you can't do this, but for new code that doesn't have any such constraints, this is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the `fstream` as an argument to your function by reference.

```
fstream obj;
void Modify (fstream &obj) // no return, just pass by reference
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: This is not very elegant, as you need to document what `Modify` will do with the `fstream &` and the client needs to do the allocation.

Comment: that way, initialization can't happen inside `Modify`

Comment: my idea is to actually create the stream and return it for usage by the app.